# useEffect infinite loop when fetching from the api

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to fetch some data from the API, but doesn't matter which dependencies I use, useEffect still keeps making an infinite loop, is  there something wrong in the code or why it keeps doing that?

```
function HomePage() {
    const [Carousels, setCarousels] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getCarousels = async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            const genres = ["BestRated", "Newest"];
            for (const genre of genres) {
                try {
                    const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/carousels/` + genre);
                    console.log(res.data);
                    setCarousels([...Carousels, res.data]);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            }
            setLoading(false);
        }
        getCarousels();
    }, [Carousels]);
    return (
        <div className='Home'>
            <NavBar />
            <HeroCard />
            {!loading && Carousels.map((carousel) => (
                <Carousel key={carousel._id} carousel={carousel} />
            ))}
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use effect called when Carousels changed and Carousels changed inside useEffect.

Use set state with callback

```js
function HomePage() {
    const [Carousels, setCarousels] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getCarousels = async () => {
            setLoading(true);
            const genres = ["BestRated", "Newest"];
            for (const genre of genres) {
                try {
                    const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/carousels/` + genre);
                    console.log(res.data);
                    setCarousels(carouselsPrev => [...carouselsPrev, res.data]);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            }
            setLoading(false);
        }
        getCarousels();
    }, []);
    return (
        <div className='Home'>
            <NavBar />
            <HeroCard />
            {!loading && Carousels.map((carousel) => (
                <Carousel key={carousel._id} carousel={carousel} />
            ))}
            <Footer />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I changed the setCarousels, and it stopped the infinite loop, but I don't know why, Carousels aren't updated properly, it doesn't get the response from res.data

Comment: @TrifIonut Can you log res output?

Comment: Yes, the res works just fine, but somehow it isn't added in Carousels

Comment: @TrifIonut Can you show me the output console.log(res)

Comment: This is shown from log(res.data) Array(1)
0: {_id: '627d6e54f1a6fc3a220b9ffa', title: 'Best Rated Movies', genre: 'BestRated', content: Array(10), createdAt: '2022-05-12T20:30:12.978Z', …}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Comment: And this from Carousels: Array(0)length: 0[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` in your code updates Carousels each run. It sees the updated value and runs again. You could fix it various ways, the easiest would be to add [fetched, setFetched] = useState(false); and use it in your useEffect to check before fetching from the API